# JSON object array to store data of a form in local storage temporary (PhoneGap project)

Tags: javascript, json, html, cordova

I am building a data aqusition system using PhoneGap.  .I am trying to store my form data temporary on local storage using JSON,Data should be visible after I close and reopen the application (after pressing Get Data button),But after I close it only the lastly entered record is visible

This is my code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Household Profile DB storage</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,
                                       initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,
                                       minimum-scale=1,width=device-width" />


     <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/table.css">


     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function onDeviceReady() { 
         persistData(homeId,owner,gramaND,contactNo,address,race);
        }
        function saveLocal(form){
            if (window.localStorage) {

                var fhomeId = form.homeId.value,
                    fowner = form.owner.value,
                    fgramaND = form.gramaND.value,
                    fcontactNo= form.contactNo.value,
                    faddress = form.address.value,
                    frace = form.race.value;




                alert("hi");
                var highscores = [{"homeId": fhomeId,
                                   "owner":fowner,
                                   "gramaND":fgramaND,
                                   "contactNo":fcontactNo,
                                   "address":faddress,
                                   "race":frace}];
                localStorage.setItem("highscores",JSON.stringify(highscores));

                alert("The data has been stored successfully.");
            } else {
                alert("Your Browser does not support LocalStorage.");
            }
        }

        function readLocal(){
            if (window.localStorage) {

                var scores =[];
                //Get the highscores object
                scores = localStorage.getItem("highscores");
                scores = JSON.parse(scores);
                for (i=0;i<scores.length;i++){



                    var text = "homeId :"+scores[i].homeId +"<br>"+
                                "owner:"+ scores[i].owner+"<br>"+
                                "address"+scores[i].address +"<br>"+
                                "gramaND"+scores[i].gramaND +"<br>"+
                                "contactNo"+scores[i].contactNo+"<br>" +
                                '<Button value="DELETE" onclick="'+scores.splice(i, 0)+'><>/Button>';


                            var tbodyx = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
                            var tr=document.createElement("TR");
                            var td=document.createElement("TD");
                            td.innerHTML = text;
                            tr.appendChild(td);
                            tbody.appendChild(tr);


                }
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <!--/header-->  
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline" data-theme="b">

            <a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back">Back</a>
            <h1>Household Profile</h1>
            <a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Menu</a>

        </div>
        <!--/header-->

        <div id="wrapper">
             <form id="userInput" action ="" method="GET"> 
                <div data-role="content">


                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label > Home ID </label> 
                        <input class="inputClass" id="homeId" placeholder="H0001" value="" data-mini="true" type="text">
                    </div>


                    <div  data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label > Owner </label> 
                        <input class="inputClass" id="owner" placeholder="Aberathne" value="" type="text">
                    </div>


                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label  class="select">GramaNiladhari Division</label>
                            <select class="inputClass" id="gramaND">
                                <option value="GramaNiladhari Division 1">GramaNiladhari Division 1</option>
                                <option value="GramaNiladhari Division 2">GramaNiladhari Division 2</option>
                                <option value="GramaNiladhari Division 3">GramaNiladhari Division 3</option>
                                <option value="GramaNiladhari Division 4">GramaNiladhari Division 4</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>


                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label > Contact No </label> 
                        <input  class="inputClass" id="contactNo" placeholder="071-9545-073" value="" type="number">
                    </div>


                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label >Address:</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8"  class="inputClass" id="address"></textarea>
                    </div>


                    <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="submit" data-theme="d">Location in a Map</button></div>


                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label  >Race</label>
                            <select  class="inputClass" id="race">
                                <option value=" Sinhalese"> Sinhalese</option>
                                <option value=" Sri Lanka Tamils"> Sri Lanka Tamils</option>
                                <option value=" Moors"> Moors</option>
                                <option value=" Indian Tamils "> Indian Tamils </option>
                                <option value=" Malays "> Malays </option>
                                <option value=" Burghers ">  Burghers </option>

                            </select>
                    </div>

                    <input class="buttonClass" type="button" value="Insert Data" onclick="saveLocal(this.form);">

                 </div>
             </form>
         </div>

        <input class="buttonClass" type="button" value="get Data" onclick="readLocal();">
      <!--  <p id="dhomeId"></p>
        <p id="downer"></p>
        <p id="dgramaND"></p>
        <p id="dcontactNo"></p>
        <p id="daddress"></p>
        <p id="drace"></p>-->



        <table border="1">
            <tbody id="tbody">
                <tr><td>test1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>test2</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>




    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Also I need to expand my code to edit and delete record from local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it should only show the last entered JSON. You're not appending the scores rather you're replacing it. When you are executing the command

```
localStorage.setItem("highscores",JSON.stringify(highscores));
```

you just **replaced** previous `highscores` value on the localStorage. I can't see any **append** mechanism in your code. What you need to do is retrieve the previous JSON data, add the new highscores with previous data and then save it again.

Comment: So sorry for the late response,can u explain it little bit,This is the first time I am using JSON in my project